# Modifying Vertex Normals

Tags: normals

[image]

I am trying to create foliage for my game. However, the shading is weird and unnatural. So, I went on to research how to fix this. I found this image on Polycount that explains how to fix the issue. It is about modifying the normals. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I read about using Normal Edit Modifier but I saw no changes when I tried.